# if Quick means "moving fast", why Car is quick does not work?

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, adjectives

I have always learned that quick relates to more to time (a quick break) and fast relates more to physical speed.

However, Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries state that Quick:

> Moving fast or doing something in a short time.

In addition, there are sample sentences with both quick and fast, such as:

> ‘While being quick and fast, those involved in the relief and rescue
>   work should maintain their temper, he noted.’

In this sentence, what is the meaning of both then?

Comment: The question is actually two questions. What you're asking is unclear. And the first question contains a false premise. *The car is quick* "works" just fine, as you could see from a google search of the phrase using quotation marks. 

*The train is quick* is also a fine way to say that a train is fast or that a ride on a train from here to there doesn't take very long. Again, if you google it, you'll see plenty of examples. 

Finally, we often repeat two words with the same or similar meanings for emphasis. The meaning of both *quick* and *fast* in the sentence given is to work quickly.

Comment: @JimReynolds Interesting, a native speaker (BrE) I consulted said that he would never use quick for physical speed, as in "I like quick cars".

Comment: "I like quick cars" google search > 11,600 results

Comment: @JimReynolds Well I can find thousands of hits for things like double negative or other informal constructions but that does not make it proper grammar. The dictionary explicitly says that "quick cars" is not correct usage.

Comment: What is the definition of "proper" grammar? How do you know when an utterance is proper grammar or not?

Comment: @JimReynolds Well as long as it follows established rules and/or it is supported by a trustworthy dictionary,

Comment: I personally suggest you re-write the question. If you'd like to discuss it in chat, I'm happy to. Does *Frogs clown lazily to green bicycle dreams* follow an established grammar rule? Does it violate one? Dictionaries are not grammars.

Comment: I'd like to know which dictionary "explicitly says that _quick cars_ is not correct usage."

Comment: @J.R.I think it was the Oxford dictionary in its Learners section, I will try to find it.

Comment: JohnV - I'm guessing you are referring to [this usage note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Penu9.png), which is found under [OALD's entry for _quick_](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/quick_1?q=quick). Even what you read there should be taken with a grain of salt. Notice how it says: _These adjectives are **frequently used** with the following nouns_ (not "**always** used"); _`fast` is **used especially** for things that move at great speed_ (not "used **only**"); _`quick` is **more often used** to describe something done in a short time_ (not "**exclusively** used").

Comment: This is why, if you try to say, "_Fast car_ is the same as _quick car_," or "_Fast car_ is just as good as _quick car_," you'll get an argument. However, if you say, "_Quick car_ is always wrong; it should be _fast car_ instead," you'll also get an argument. Sometimes one word is usually better than another, but that doesn't make the other word "wrong" or "incorrect" or "improper grammar", especially in all circumstances and contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the words are related and synonymous in many contexts, they don't quite mean the same thing in all situations.

For example, a slow cat can have quick reflexes.

One person on Yahoo Answers wrote:

> I like quick cars but not necessarily fast.

I would take this to mean the writer enjoys a car that can move quickly out of an intersection, but doesn't necessarily cruise at a high speed on the autobahn.

Had the writer said, "I like fast cars but not necessarily quick," then I would assume they would want a car that could easily travel 200 kph on the expressway, but wouldn't care if it's a little sluggish getting started at a red light.

Also, some adjectives simply get associated with certain nouns more than others. And sometimes synonymous words get paired together for emphasis. In a sentence like the one you quoted, for example:

> "Relief workers need to be quick and fast," he said.

The speaker is conveying a sense of urgency, and not necessarily expecting anyone to parse those two words carefully, and discern some subtle difference between two.

Comment: I have also seen this kind of usage when it - I believe - refers to the ability accelerate. Something like "the car accelerates quickly but does not drive very fast".

Answer (score 0):

**Quick** can apply to both time and speed.

I would note that **quick** has an implication of *agile*, while **fast** doesn't.

You can totally say **"The car is quick."** There are no problems there.

Comment: Well but you do not normally say "That train is quick", I am sure "fast" is more natural

Comment: @JohnV Yes, that's because trains are generally not very *agile*. They are heavy, slow to accelerate and can only move along a fixed track.